# css background does not work in safari

Tags: css, safari

The following style applied to body tag does not work in safari. The issue is with the color #faf5ef. It shows black in safari (v 5.1.7). Could anyone suggest what the issue could be and how to fix it?

```css
 body {
    background: url(images/body_bg.png) no-repeat top center #faf5ef;   
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Try `background: #faf5ef url(images/body_bg.png) no-repeat top center;`

Comment: What OS and version of Safari?

Comment: I am using windows7 to test this. The issue was reported when viewed on ipad. Safari version is 5.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure your issue is the **PNG**

Try going to an image editor(like Photoshop) and making the bg into a bigger width(I assume you have it at 1px-10px) like 20px-25px...

Also saving them as **non-interlaced png** helps.

Looking at your image it looks like its transparency so **remove the transparency**.

And **have it the right height**.

Try that.

HEre is an example of an working image (jpg)
http://cssdeck.com/labs/68urshrp

This works (on iPad) so it shows the **png needs edit**

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of parameters like this:

```
background: #faf5ef url(images/body_bg.png) no-repeat top center;
```

Color at the end isn't a standard way anyway and it's a small miracle it works anywhere else.

In general, with the shorthand `background` property the values should be in this order:

```
background: color image repeat attachment position;
```

Any of them could be omitted but they still should be in the same order.

Comment: This one does not change the color either. It still displays black

Comment: I updated the same css using the image on my website http://cssdeck.com/labs/h2udsojr. it still has that issue

Comment: As I stated its the **PNG**

Comment: ...try taking a look at the [image file alone](http://diligentbrainteam.com/BFS/images/body_bg.png), I think you'll see where the problem is.

Comment: Yes I see the issue you need to resave the png to the methods I explained...y

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
background: url(images/body_bg.png)
```

Use like this

```
background: url('images/body_bg.png')
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-color: #faf5ef;
```

Comment: looks like half of the bottom half of the page is showing correct color. I see that there is another style (user agent stylesheet) for body. display:block;